# nestjs typeorm write same query to different databases

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I don't have enough information to give you but Im tring to write the same query to different databases (one is Postgres and the other one is MongoDB). Searched the web for hours and still no clue.
Anyone by any chance knows how to do it/ can refer me to the docs? Im working on NestJS & TypeORM

Comment: What makes you think it is possible?

Comment: This is **not going to happen**, no matter what your  obscurification (NestJS & TypeORM) layers claim. It is difficult enough to write a query for 2 different databases with the same underlying concepts (say Postgres and DB2 - both RDBMS). However, MongoDB is based on totally different underlying concept. A (NoSql) document orientated database.